# How to find storage location of images in tiny mice

Tags: php, upload, tinymce, e-commerce, image-uploading

I'm in the process of migrating data from k-ecommerce platform to magento eCommerce platform. I stuck with getting product images from k-ecommerce platform. In their backend, they are using tiny mce editor to upload images and direct uploads also there. 
I could find some of product images in shown image folder. But others are not found. 
I suspect, 'shown images' are direct upload images and 'not found images' are uploaded through the tiny mce editor. 
Does tiny mce store images in database?

Can anyone give me a clue to find those images that uploaded through the tiny mce editor.

'filesystem.rootpath' configuration in config.php sets to upload folder

EDIT

Image path of in tiny mce popup is like this. I again suspect it get data from database.

../../stream/index.php?cmd=im.streamFile&path={0}/product_folder/image_name.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i am not that familiar with the tinymce uploadmanager, but i think images are stored here:  `tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/files/`

Comment: There is no such a directory called 'files' in 'imagemanager' directory

Comment: do you know with which uploadmanager the files have been uploaded?

Comment: This is the url of upload manager. /scripts/tiny_mce/plugins/imagemanager/pages/im/index.html I think it's imagemanager. Is it  you are asking?